# Android LocationListener stop receiving location updates

Tags: android, android-location

I have registered a `location listener`, which will receive location updates using `NETWORK_PROVIDER`. The listener receives location updates if the `activity` is in foreground. If I leave the app, after some time it stops receiving location updates. Which is a bit weird... isn't it supposed to receive location update even if none of the activity is on the stack? The listener starts receiving location updates again if I go back to my app.

Or am I doing something wrong? What programming model is suggested to receive location updates even if none of my activity is not active (neither on foreground, nor on stack)?

There are some other way to receive location updates (using pending intent), but those do not trigger if I do not turn on GPS.

Comment: If you want to recieve the location when the activity is sleeping, you need a wake lock and a service.

Comment: You mean I should write a service? and that service should implement LocationListener?

And what did you mean by wake lock? 

Any link or example of what you mentioned?

Comment: I read about wake lock. I do not want wake lock. Because I do not want the device to be awake. The device behave normally. User should be able to lock screen if he wants.

Making the listener a service would make more sense. But I am not sure if that will be right approach.

Comment: @JahidShohel did you solved the problem? if yes, can you please share me the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The activity in the background will be eventually destroyed, you don't have any guarantee that once stopped it will continue receiving location updates. Activities in Android are not supposed to be used like this.

You can use a service with a wake lock as suggested, but keeping the device awake will quickly drain your battery.

I recommend you [this talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=twmuBbC_oB8) by Reto Meier (IO 2011), where he talks about different strategies to have a fresh location. Here is [the code](http://code.google.com/p/android-protips-location/).

Comment: Thanks for the good link to the video. There is quite a lot of important topics covered in the talk. The part about receiving location updates is from about 20min50sec till 26min00sec.